# How can i replace ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY in PHP versions below 5.6

Tags: php

In PHP 5.6 i can do

```
print_r(array_filter([0=>'numeric', 'x' => 'string'], 'is_string', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

and get

```
Array
(
    [x] => string
)
```

What is the simplest way to simulate this in older PHP versions?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
function array_filter_use_key($array, $callback) {
  return array_intersect_key($array, array_fill_keys(array_filter(array_keys($array), $callback), TRUE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest? I suppose you just use a classic `foreach()` loop and push qualifying key-value pairs into a new result array.

```
$filtered = [];
foreach ([0 => 'numeric', 'x' => 'string'] as $key => $val) {
    if (is_string($key)) {
        $filtered[$key] = $val;
    }
}
var_export($filtered);
```